# Python read current url to store it session for later comeback

Tags: python, django

I am on url : /main/a=11&b=22

I want to store this in my session to come back to this page later

How can fetch this url with all the parmeters like this.

```
url = fetch_function(currnet_url) 
print url 
/main/a=11&b=22
request.session['url'] = url
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `request.get_full_path()` method. Read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path